# What is device COM-MID1 in my router settings?

Tags: router, home-networking

I see this listed in my home router:

```
Device : COM-MID1
```

It has an IP address, but is not connected. Could this be anything to do with me trying to connect a TV to my home network?

Just in case it's relevant the router is a BT 2700HGV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see it seems to be a generic name for media devices like TVs or Blu-Ray players, probably used when the router cannot detect the actual model name. So yes, it's most likely the result of your trying to hook up your TV.

Comment: Thank you.  I agree, especially now I have collected more evidence.

Answer (score 11):

I have that in my list.  It is my Panasonic Smart TV.

Comment: Mentioning 'panasonic' did help.

Comment: Yes I got Panasonic TV. This is the IP you can use for DLNA streaming to the TV

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the mac address you can do a lookup and find out the manufacturer which might give you a clue

Comment: For example, here's a site that let me lookup my mystery `COM-MID1` device:  http://aruljohn.com/mac/CC7EE7